# Compiler design prevent register override

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, compiler

I'm trying to write a compiler for a self-designed CPU with accompanying instruction set. The CPU has 3 registers, 2 input registers (B and C) and one output register (D). When for example an ADD instruction is executed the sum of B and C is calculated and stored in D.

I'm trying to write the compiler with the visitor design pattern: I have a bunch of language tree classes like "IfStatement", "Addition", "Integer" and a visitor "Compiler". The visitor would look at each node of the tree and append bytecode to the end of the bytecode list. I can't figure out how to cleanly handle register overrides: when evaluating the expression

```
2*(7+3)
```

the generated bytecode is

```
PUTb 2
PUTb 7
PUTc 3
ADD
MOVE D C
MUL
```

As you can see the 2 is overridden by the 7.
I want the compiler to realize it can reverse the order to

```
(7+3)*2
```

or that it can store temporary result is RAM, using some other instructions, this will certainly be necessary for more complex expressions like

```
(7-5)*(8+3)
```

Is there a clean/object-oriented way to handle this? Is the Visitor pattern not appropriate here? Do I need to look at some advanced techniques like register coloring? The compiler will be written in Java, bu I don't think that really matters.

Comment: Your real problem appears to be an incorrectly constructed parse tree. Or perhaps your visitor should be prepending operations (assuming a top-down traversal). In either case, Stack Overflow would probably be a better place to post, but you'd need to show your code and how the particular expression transforms into a parse tree.

Comment: @kdgregory I don't actually have a parse tree, I have a AST. The object representation of that first expression looks like this: Multiplication(2, Addition(7, 3)). I don't think there is anything wrong there, the problem is that I'm naively traversing the AST.

Comment: Here's a hint: you can only emit bytecode for an operation _after_ you've emitted bycode for the operations that it depends on. Therefore, you should emit _all_ bytecode for the addition before you emit _any_ bytecode for the multiplication. This will turn into a depth-first traversal of your "object representation," where bytecode for the node is emitted after bytecode for both of its child nodes.

Comment: @kdgregory I think that's what I'm doing right now: the first child (2) is put in register B, the second child (7+3) is calculated and put in register C. Then the multiplication itself is carried out. The problem is that calculating the second child overrides the first child.

Comment: Here's what you said above: "it can store temporary result is RAM". What _aren't_ you doing?

Comment: I want the compiler to realise that it can store temporary results in RAM. I'm asking how I can design my code to do this.

Comment: Have you tried reserving a section of RAM that can be used for a stack?

Comment: I am mainly trying to design a compiler right now, but I could do that in the future. A hardcoded stack size seems like a less elegant solution, and a re-sizable stack open the door to a bunch of other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need an overflow area, perhaps a stack, or some chunk of memory.

You'll also want to get the generated code correct before optimizing it, because optimizing broken code is basically impossible.

So , given a stack, you should have something like: `PUT b,2; Push b; Put b,7; Put c,3; ADD; Pop b; MUL` and if using memory, `PUT b,2; Store b @1; Put b,7; Put c,3; ADD; Load b @1; MUL`.  Next, to get the optimization, you can have a separate pass that balances the tree, by changing the order of the operands based on simple weight.

### EDIT:

You create a data structure that tracks the contents of the registers (you might assume empty at statement start).  Each time you generate an instruction you update that data structure to mark what is in it (e.g. what tree node and/or what operand, i.e.variable or constant, or overflow temporary variable).

Before you generate an operation, you ensure that its sources are in the registers as needed, and if not you perform a load from the overflow area, or variable area, or constant area/immediates, or from another register.

(By design, you shouldn't have the case where you need to generate anything else at this point other than a load of some kind, e.g. if you are about to generate the MUL, you won't have to generate an ADD, because that should have been handled already in by the appropriate visiting traversal.)

But -- before you do any load of operands (which will overwrite the register) you generate a store to an overflow area if there is anything being tracked.  Also do the same for the target/output register (e.g. of MUL).  And the whole time updating your tracking structure so the next instruction generated will have the state of the registers & overflow temps as of the current point in the code.

Comment: I am asking how to make the compiler understand that register B will be overridden and that it needs to store it temporarily in RAM (using Store and Load instructions) in a cleanly designed way.

Comment: @ToddSewell: Initially, the compiler should simply assume that both register B and C contain valuable information that needs to be preserved. After that, you could start optimizing by dropping unneeded stores.

Comment: But that delays the problem: how do I detect unneeded stores?

Comment: @Todd see my update

Comment: Is the overflow/memory area also tracked by the same data structure? And what do you mean by "if there is anything being tracked" in your last paragraph?

Comment: If you use a stack for the overflow area, and have a simple language/AST to traverse and simple code generator, you probably won't need to track the overflow area, because you can design it so that it turns out that what you need is always the top of the stack.  (The stack can simply reflects the preorder traversal.)  If you use an array instead, you'll probably need to track those locations, unless, you either manage it like a stack, or use a new location for every temporary you need.

Comment: One of the things you track is nothing aka empty aka free aka available.  This is the state you should expect for all registers on start of code generation for a statement.

Comment: But my target CPU doesn't have a stack, it has integer addressed RAM. Or does "stack" refer to the data structure in the compiler?

Comment: When I say stack here, I'm referring to what many processors have, which is sometimes known as the thread stack, the runtime stack, or the call stack.  The processor support is that you can push and pop, and the operating system and calling convention work together to make sure that there is stack available to each invoked method...  However, this is just memory together with a push and pop capability that can surely be had on a non-stack capable machine (even if push or pop takes multiple instructions each).

Comment: However, it seems to me that for your simple machine, you might rather make the overflow as simple as taking a new memory location each time you have need of a temporary, which will keep your code generator simple (i.e. consider figuring out how to reuse temporary memory locations as an initially unnecessary optimization).